# What word is implied by "'uffy"?

Tags: word-meaning

What word is implied by "'uffy"? It should mean "peevish" or something, judging by the context. Wells's short story Mr. Brisher's Treasure

> And days I was that dull, it made Jane regular **'uffy**. 'You ain't the same chap you was in London,' she says, several times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word **'uffy** is the dropped-haitch version of **huffy**.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/huffy) has

> **huffy**
> angry and offended
> *I told her she'd made a mistake and she got huffy with me.*

The quote's

> it made Jane regular 'uffy

paraphrases as

> it really annoyed Jane

Being in the vernacular is shown by the following ungrammatical

> You ain't the same chap you was

Comment: I am enjoying re-reading Wells' short stories, so as to be ready for Sergey's next question (unless he switches authors!)

Comment: I wrote 'dropped-haitch' rather than 'dropped-aitch' because many people who [drop their aitches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-dropping) add them inappropriately where they ain't, perhaps in mockery of people who 'speak proper', such as "what an orrible hexperience".